# SQL Equations from Aliases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with multiple aliases for SUM equations.

Now I need to use those aliases in a larger equation, but can't use the alias names in the same query apparently. In one case, I need a total of about 7 aliases summed together, subtracting two other aliases summed together. Is there a simple way to do this? Using SQL Server

For Example -

```
ISNULL((SELECT  SUM(Addendums)
        FROM    v_Addendums
        WHERE   Job_ID = JM.Job_ID
                AND (JC.FundingType_ID <> 1 OR JC.FundingType_ID IS NULL)
                AND jobPhase_CompletedDate <= @dt1
                AND (Addendum_Date between @dt1-31 and @dt1)),0) AS Earn30,

ISNULL((SELECT  SUM(JM1.Draw_Amount) 
        FROM DrawSchedule AS JM1 INNER JOIN
             JobContracts AS JC1 ON JM1.Job_ID = JC1.Job_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
             v_JobPhase ON JC1.Job_ID = v_JobPhase.Job_ID AND 
             JM1.JobPhase_ID = v_JobPhase.PhaseType_ID
        WHERE   (v_JobPhase.Completed IS NOT NULL)
            AND (JC.FundingType_ID <> 1 OR JC.FundingType_ID IS NULL)
            AND (v_JobPhase.Completed BETWEEN @dt1 - 61 AND @dt1-31) 
            AND (JM1.Job_ID = JM.Job_ID)),0) +
ISNULL((SELECT  SUM(Addendums)
        FROM    v_Addendums
        WHERE   Job_ID = JM.Job_ID
            AND (JC.FundingType_ID <> 1 OR JC.FundingType_ID IS NULL)
            AND jobPhase_CompletedDate <= @dt1
            AND (Addendum_Date between @dt1-61 and @dt1-31)),0) AS Earn60
```

Say I need to add Earn30 + Earn60.. then subtract another similar alias.

Comment: You need to post your code for someone to be able to directly comment on your solution.  But yes there are ways and it will depend on the RDBMS that you are using so you should tag that too (e.g. sql-server, oracle, etc.)  More than likely you will want to create all of the sums in a common table expression [cte] or derived table then reference your aliased columns for your last equation

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I added your suggestions to my question.

Comment: read up on Common Table Expression [CTE] it will probably be a bit easier understand at first than derived table for you because you can separate your logic easier.  Also without seeing all of your query all I can say is that first glance suggests to me there are other ways of writing this query that you might benefit performance wise from. Also not to complicate matters but you could also assign the parts of these to variables if you are truly only dealing with 1 row/set of values.

Comment: Thanks Matt, @Matt .. Don't have time to rewrite the query at the time being, just have to use what's there.. Unfortunely not just dealing with one set of values.. have to loop the query results. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CTE tables (common Table Expressions) for SQL Server.
e.g.

```
;with mycte as (
select 1 as line1 -- this is your statement with whatever and assigning it an alias
)

select
 line1 -- this is your alias column from the previous mycte
 , line1+1 as line2 -- just an example of playing with the alias
 from mycte
```